# Single Retry and DLT topic for multiple topics listener with @RetryableTopic

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I have below configuration for listener

```
@RetryableTopic(
        attempts = "3",
        backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000, multiplier = 3.0, maxDelay = 60000, random = true),
        autoCreateTopics = "false",
        exclude = {
            JsonProcessingException.class,
            NullPointerException.class,
            IllegalStateException.class,
            IllegalArgumentException.class,
            UnsupportedOperationException.class,
            ConstraintViolationException.class,
            InvalidRequestException.class},
        autoStartDltHandler = "false",
        topicSuffixingStrategy = TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE)
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${spring.kafka.consumer.properties.topics}'.split('\\s+')}")
...
```

and in properties i listed all related topics:

```
... topics: >
          transaction_events_raw_v1
          card_events_raw_v1
          authorisation_events_raw_v1
```

As you know multiple RETRY and DLT topics will be created with below naming format:

```
transaction_events_raw_v1_retry-0
transaction_events_raw_v1_retry-1
transaction_events_raw_v1_dlt
card_events_raw_v1_retry-0
card_events_raw_v1_retry-1
card_events_raw_v1_dlt
authorisation_events_raw_v1_retry-0
authorisation_events_raw_v1_retry-1
authorisation_events_raw_v1_dlt
```

I would like to know is it possible to create single RETRY and DLT topics in this case?

```
domain_events_retry-0
domain_events_retry-1
domain_events_dlt
```

Tried to override RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory and manipulate with retry and dead letter topic names however having duplicate key issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key null (attempted merging values DestinationTopic{destinationName='domain_events_retry', properties=Properties{delayMs=8605, suffix='-retry-0', type=RETRY, maxAttempts=3, numPartitions=1, dltStrategy=ALWAYS_RETRY_ON_ERROR, kafkaOperations=org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate@70b196d3, shouldRetryOn=org.springframework.kafka.retrytopic.DestinationTopicPropertiesFactory$$Lambda$841/0x00000008006b2840@5c997de8, timeout=-1}} and DestinationTopic{destinationName='domain_events_retry', properties=Properties{delayMs=27926, suffix='-retry-1', type=RETRY, maxAttempts=3, numPartitions=1, dltStrategy=ALWAYS_RETRY_ON_ERROR, kafkaOperations=org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate@70b196d3, shouldRetryOn=org.springframework.kafka.retrytopic.DestinationTopicPropertiesFactory$$Lambda$841/0x00000008006b2840@45bf93bb, timeout=-1}})
```

Regards,

--Samir

Comment: You need to show your RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory and the full stack trace.